# Error: Could not resolve 'app.history' from state ' '

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am writing unit test which is using $stateProvider(the code is shown below for both the code and its test file).While executing this, it is giving error- "Error: Could not resolve **'app.history' from state '**'".

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app',       
     {   
        url: "/app",    
        templateUrl: "pages/app/index.html",
        controller: function($state)    {
        $state.go('app.history');
    }})
    .state('app.history', 
         { url: "/history", 
           templateUrl: "pages/app/modules/History/partials/history.html"
          })
```

**Unit test code -**

```
describe("Unit tests for config.jst", function() {
  var $rootScope, $injector, $state;
  beforeEach(module('ui.router'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_, _$injector_, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $injector = _$injector_;
    $state = _$state_;

    $templateCache.put("pages/app/index.html", "");
    $templateCache.put("pages/app/modules/History/partials/history.html", "");
}));

describe("states", function() {
    var state = "app.history";
    it("verify state configuration", function() {
        //var config = $state.get(state);
        $state.go(state);
        $rootScope.$digest();
        //console.log($state);
        expect($state.current.name).to.be.equal(state);
    });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include application module.

Add

`module('your_application_module_name');`

below

`beforeEach(module('ui.router'));`